# Sklearn Chi2 return NaN results

Tags: statistics, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, p-value

I attempting evaluate my feature results by performing a chi-squared test using sklearns chi2 library http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html.

I used the methods in this thread: [Python sklearn - how to calculate p-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306341/python-sklearn-how-to-calculate-p-values) in order to obtain my p-values. A cutout of my p-values looks like:

```
nan, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9999999999999872, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan
```

I have a very large number of nan's. Why is this? Does this mean my results are insignificant assuming a 0.05 significance test?

Comment: What kind of data are you fitting in?

Comment: My data is a vectorized version of text features (words or phrases), taken from a large text corpus. My target data are scores. For example, there would be a score (0 - 100) associated with every data entry, which would be a large number of sentences.