# How to output p-values for sci-kit learn regression models? Any other Python options?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataframe with 5 columns. I delete one column and define this as `y`, the dependent variable. I will use the other 4 columns x1, x2, x3, x4 or matrix `X` to predict this variable with some sort of regression modeling.

For example:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

`clf.coef_` will have the regression coefficients, i.e. `clf.coef_` gives me the coefficient for each variable. My question is how do I find the P value for each variable?

Also, in comparing multiple `sklearn` models (here `skearn.linear_model`), how do I plot these to see the effects of linear regression vs lasso vs. ridge regression, etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find p-value (significance) in scikit-learn LinearRegression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression)