# Obtaining summary from logistic regression(Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
model = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
model.fit(X2, Y2)
Y2_prob=model.predict_proba(X2)[:,1]
```

I've built a logistic regression model on my training dataset X2 and Y2. Now is it possible for me to obtain the coefficients and p values from here?
Because:

```
model.summary()
```

gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Or can somebody help me suggest an alternative to obtain the important and significant features from this model? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find p-value (significance) in scikit-learn LinearRegression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression)

Answer (score 6):

No. Its not possible to get the p-values from here. You can get the coefficients however by using `model.coef_`. If you need the p-values you'll have to use the `statsmodels` package. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression#27928411) if you want to modify the `sklearn` class to get the p-values

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an older model of LogisticRegression. model.summary2() should do the trick.

Comment: When I try this, I get `AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute 'summary2'`. Can you clarify what version of sklearn you're using?

Comment: summary2() method is available for LogitResults class in statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model module not for sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statements to fix this problem. 
It worked in my case.

from scipy import stats
stats.chisqprob = lambda chisq, df:stats.chi2.sf(chisq, df)