# Find p-value and F-statistics in scikit learn RandomForestRegressor

Tags: scikit-learn, statistics, regression, random-forest, p-value

How can I find p-value and F-statistics in following regression task with Random Forest Regressor

```python
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=76)
result = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=crossvalidation, n_jobs=-1, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error")
rms = sqrt(result.mean() * -1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression

Comment: p-value and F-statistics of what exactly?

Comment: Not a duplicate. I think you want to look at resampling (eg. bootstrapping) to numerically estimate the p-value from the model.