# Different p-value of logistic regression in SPSS and statsmodels

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, spss

I tried to do the univariate analysis (binary logistic regression, one feature each time) in Python with statsmodel to calculate the p-value for a different feature.

```
for f_col in f_cols:
    model = sm.Logit(y,df[f_col].astype(float))
    result = model.fit()
    features.append(str(result.pvalues).split('   ')[0])
    pvals.append(str(result.pvalues).split('   ')[1].split('\n')[0])

df_pvals = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(features, pvals)), 
           columns =['features', 'pvals']) 
df_pvals
```

However, the result in the SPSS is different. The p-value of `NYHA` in the `sm.Logit` method is 0. And all of the p-values are different.
[image]

1. Is it right to use `sm.Logit` in the statsmodel to do the binary logistic regression?
2. Why there is a difference between the results? Probably `sm.Logit` use L1 regularization?
3. How should I get the same?

Many thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression#42677750

Comment: `add_constant`, You are missing the constant that statsmodels doesn't add automatically when formulas are not used.

Answer (score 0):

SPSS regression modeling procedures include constant or intercept terms automatically, unless they're told not to do so. As Josef mentions, statsmodels appears to require you to explicitly add an intercept.