# Finding p and t value in LinearRegression using sci-kit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression

I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27928411/10166058), a way to calculate p and f statistic using Sci-Kit Learn.  But what I don't understand is,

1. Why is SSE divided by `x.shape[0] - x.shape[1]`.
2. I may be wrong, But Isn't this component called the ***Degrees of Freedom***, for which the formula is

> ***n-k-1*** where **n**:= No. of observed values, **k**:= no. of predictors

Comment: Please **proofread** after posting - your link was unclickable (edited).

Comment: can you please include the relevant code, can't really see where this is coming from