# Sklearn: Linear Regression, Model Analysis. statsmodels.api Summay Equivalent

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats


X2 = sm.add_constant(toTrainX)
est = sm.OLS(toTrainY, X2)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())
```

This would give me a Holistic Picture of the model,
Like

```
            coef       std    err          t      P>|t|        [0.025      0.975]
Intercept   3.2        0.01   0.02        21311    0.000          3.1        3.3
X1         13.2        0.01   0.02        21311    0.000         13.1       13.3
X2         33.2        0.11   0.12        12       0.400         13.1       213.3
--  --  --         ---   ---   ---          ---  --   ---   ---   ---     ---    ---
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
Omnibus:                     764.278   Durbin-Watson:                   2.013
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):             8512.556
Skew:                           0.185   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Kurtosis:                       2.878   Cond. No.                     1.22e+17
```

How could I get the same for my SkLean LinearRegression Model

```
LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
#linreg.coef_ & linreg.intercept_ 
# Are Also not matching with est2.summary()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the responses to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928275/find-p-value-significance-in-scikit-learn-linearregression) it is not immediately possible with base Sklearn. However, an answer references [this file](https://gist.github.com/brentp/5355925) for extending the `LinearRegression` class to compute t stats and p-values for each of coefficients.

As for why they differ, [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/difference-between-statsmodel-ols-and-scikit-linear-regression) attempts to explain why some difference in results is to be expected.

Comment: Also ,
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_regression
f_statistic, p_value = f_regression(X_train, y_train)
f_statistic, p_value